# Combining find command conditions

Tags: linux, unix, find

I am trying to combine 2 find commands to pipe to a grep pattern match.

my 3 commands are:

**get files modified in the last 24 hours:**

```
find '/logs' -mtime 0 -type f
```

**ignore a couple of directories:**

```
find -type d \( -path /dir -o -path /dir2 -o -path /dir3 \) -prune -o -print
```

**find pattern in the file's lines:**

```
grep -rnw -e "my pattern"
```

I have gotten below to work but cant seem to add directory skipping into the mix.

**get files modified in the last 24 hours and find pattern in the file's lines:**

```
find '/logs' -mtime 0 -type f | xargs grep -rnwI -e "my pattern"
```

So ideally I would like to combine getting files modified in the last 24 hours and ignoring directories.

Comment: try find '/logs' -mtime 0 -type f  | grep -v DIRTOEXCLUDE | xargs grep -rnwI -e "my pattern"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find '/logs' ! -path "*/dir1/*" ! -path "*/dir2/*" ! -path "*/dir3/* -mtime 0 -type f | xargs grep -rnwI -e "my pattern"
```

or

```
find '/logs' -mtime 0 -type f | egrep -v "dir1|dir2|dir3" | xargs grep -rnwI -e "my pattern"
```

Comment: I like that egrep is a little cleaner

Comment: use of egrep is deprecated in POSIX, use `grep -E` from `man grep` `In addition, three variant programs egrep, fgrep and rgrep are available.  egrep is the same as grep -E.  fgrep is the same as grep -F.  rgrep is the same as grep -r.  Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is  deprecated,
       but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this slow solution can solve your problem:

```
find '/logs' -mtime 0 -type f | grep -v dir | grep -v dir2 | grep -v dir3| xargs grep -rnwI -e "my pattern"
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe not use find at all but the recursive abilities of grep along with --exclude-dir option (or maybe the --exclude-from option see `man grep` for details).

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2 --exclude-dir=dir3 -nwI -e "my pattern" /logs*
```

Comment: hmm I had not thought of this approach, I'll try it out and see if it is faster.